# Closing a JDialog by hitting the "enter" on keyboard

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I want to close my JDialog by hitting the "enter" key on my keyboard. how can I do that? thank you!
NOTE:
I want to do this, without any button involved.
THank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way:

- You could give it a close JButton
- whose ActionListener has code that closes the dialog,
- And make that button the default button for the dialog's rootpane.

---

e.g.,

```
myDialog.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(exitButton);
```

---

Option two:

- Use Key Bindings to bind the enter key to exit code in an AbstractAction.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class DemoDialog {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
      frame.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(400, 300)));
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);

      final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Dialog", true);

      // set binding
      int condition = JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
      InputMap inputMap = ((JPanel) dialog.getContentPane()).getInputMap(condition);
      ActionMap actionMap = ((JPanel) dialog.getContentPane()).getActionMap();
      String enter = "enter";
      inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), enter);
      actionMap.put(enter, new AbstractAction() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dialog.dispose();
         }
      });

      dialog.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(200, 200)));
      dialog.pack();
      dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
      dialog.setVisible(true);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to say first that 'Hovercraft Full Of Eels' solution is more elegant than this one and more closely in the spirit of the `JDialog` and `Swing` API. However, to offer an alternative here is a basic example of using a `KeyListener` on your `JDialog` that will do as you need without adding a button;

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JDialog jd = new JDialog();

    // Add and define the KeyListener here!
    jd.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){  

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // Nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // Nothing 
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                JDialog d = (JDialog)e.getSource();
                d.dispose();
                }
            }
        });        
    // End key listener code
        jd.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The important/relevant code is between the two main comments. This is a compilable example, so you can copy paste this into a new file and run it to view the effects.

Comment: I would never use a KeyListener for this, and in fact hardly ever use KeyListeners for Swing applications in general, given that they are very low-level listeners. Even the Swing tutorials recommend against their use in favor of Key Binding where possible.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - I agree, hence my disclaimer at the top of the answer. But they asked for a method that did not involve adding a button.